# Laravel - I deleted a migrate class manually and created it again. Now Migrate won't work

Tags: php, laravel

I created a migrate class for laravel using:

```
php artisan make:migration mymigrationclass
```

Then I deleted it manually. Then I created it again using the same name.

After that I tried to refresh my database by using:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

But now I get the error:

```
 Cannot declare class mymigrationclass, because the name is already in use
```

Probably because I deleted it manually before.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, make sure you remove it from your migrations table in db.

Answer (score 0):

Use command

```
composer dump-autoload
```